# Hudson -> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space on maven clean test package -P deploy in Hudson

Tags: maven, hudson, out-of-memory

I have a maven project in Hudson that builds with the following build options:

[image: Screenshot of Hudson maven config]

The build often fails with an OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space but I don't know why.

The failure looks like this:

```
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 38 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Feb 28 17:04:28 EST 2011
[INFO] Final Memory: 48M/95M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
channel stopped
Deploying artifacts to http://test/archiva/repository/snapshots
Deploying the main artifact pom.xml
[INFO ] Retrieving previous build number from test-archiva-default
[INFO ] Uploading project information for home-buildings 2.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO ] Retrieving previous metadata from test-archiva-default
[INFO ] Uploading repository metadata for: 'snapshot com.test.home:core:2.0-SNAPSHOT'
[INFO ] Retrieving previous metadata from test-archiva-default
[INFO ] Uploading repository metadata for: 'artifact com.test.home:core'
Deploying the main artifact core.ear
[INFO ] Retrieving previous build number from test-archiva-default
[INFO ] Retrieving previous metadata from test-archiva-default
[INFO ] Uploading repository metadata for: 'snapshot com.test.home:core-ear:2.0-SNAPSHOT'
[INFO ] Retrieving previous metadata from test-archiva-default
[INFO ] Uploading repository metadata for: 'artifact com.test.home:core-ear'
[INFO ] Uploading project information for core-ear 2.0-SNAPSHOT
Deploying the main artifact core.war
[INFO ] Retrieving previous build number from test-archiva-default
FATAL: Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Does anyone have any idea of how to stop this from occurring?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this MAVEN_OPTS is working or not. Maybe this link will be helpful, it modify the Maven startup script directly.

http://vikashazrati.wordpress.com/2007/07/26/quicktip-how-to-increase-the-java-heap-memory-for-maven-2-on-linux/

When I am facing an auto-build problem in Hudson, I will first try to emulate a build env and start the build task manually, to check if the problem can be reproduced. In this way, I can trace down the problem to Hudson or Maven.

After all, Hudson works just like a automated batch system.